# Blazor 404 Error when converting aspx pages to routing

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-4.7

I have converted my .Net 4.7 web application to a blazor application.  When I am upgrading my clients, if someone had a link to the old application such as https://gosomewhere.com/default.aspx and now because of blazor routing, it would just go to https://gosomehwere.com and it knows the route.

How can I re-route someone on a 404 error that is a Blazor Server application to the home page which is the login page?

Comment: You could add a middleware on each request that checks the URL for "aspx" endings and then re-routes your users to the desired new pages? After a while you could deactivate that middleware if most users updated their bookmarked links.
Another option would be to use the "<NotFound>" element inside the App.razor file and use some logic (NavigationManager) to redirect from there.

Comment: have converted my .Net 4.7 web application to a blazor application---What's your .net version now?